# loop to count all records based on parameter

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, conditional-statements

I have this:

```
foreach(var item in db.AInfoes)
{
    if (db.MRecords.Any(s => s.AID == item.ID))
    {
        ViewBag.RecordExists = true;
    }
    else if(!db.MRecords.Any(s => s.AID == item.ID))
    {
        ViewBag.NoRecordExists = true;
    }

}
```

The purpose of this is to hide a link in my `.cshtml` Index view.  I want to loop through the `AInfoes` table and check if any records in the `MRecords` table exist based on the foreign key, `AID` matching the primary key `ID`.

Then in the default *Index* view there is an `Edit`, `Details`, `Delete` link for each record.  I only want the `Edit` link to display if `ViewBag.NoRecordExists = true`. so if there aren't any `MRecords` for that `ID`

My CSHTML:

```
@if (!ViewBag.RecordExists)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Maintenance Record", "Edit", "MaintenanceRecords", new { id = item.ID })
}
@if (ViewBag.NoRecordExists == true)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Maintenance Record", "Edit", "MaintenanceRecords", new { id = item.ID })
}
```

In my **MRecords** db I purposely tested this by deleting all `MRecords` where `ID` equals 10.. but when I went to my Index view, the link was there for all the records.. again I only want the link to show for records where there are 0 `MRecords`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incredibly inefficient. Instead, you should simply select all the possible `AInfoes` ids, *first*, and then query for any `MRecords` that match.

```
var aInfoesIds = db.AInfoes.Select(m => m.ID).ToList();
ViewBag.RecordExists = db.MRecords.Any(m => aInfoesIds.Contains(m.AID));
```

Also, there's no need for `ViewBag.NoRecordExists`, since this is just the opposite of `RecordExists`. In your view:

```
@{ var recordExists = ViewBag.RecordExists as bool? ?? false; }
```

Then, if you want to do something only when the record *doesn't* exist, just negate it:

```
@if (!recordExists)
{
    ...
```

Comment: I have made the changes that you suggested. in my `.cshtml` I have put: `@if (recordExists)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit Maintenance Record", "Edit", "MRecords", new { id = item.ID })
            }` and I have purposely deleted all `MRecord` where `ID` equals 10. so my *Index* View for **AInfoes** should only display the *Edit* link for that record.  But instead it is showing the Edit link for all records in the **AInfoes** table even if they do have `MRecords`

Comment: That likely means that `ViewBag.RecordExists` is either evaluating to null (it's not set at all) or simply cannot be cast to a bool (it's being set to something other than a boolean type). In either case, that line of code in your view will then evaluate to `false` as the fallback.

Comment: `var aInfoesIds = db.AInfoes.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();` holds 5 values `6, 7, 8, 9 ,10`..   `ViewBag.RecordExists = db.MRecords.Any(x => aInfoesIds.Contains(x.AID));` evaluates to true.. even if there aren't any `MRecords` for 10?

Comment: Yes, because `10` is just one possibility. If there's any `MRecords` for any of the other ids, then you'll get true. It looks as if you actually want to know item by item if there's any records, not just any records for any item. If that's the case, then you can't use `ViewBag` at all. You should instead use a view model for each item, and individually set some boolean on that for each item.